# PHP UPDATE with bind_param() won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day, I'm not really familiar with PHP and i get this error when i try to execute my query.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginWithMySQLi\changenameaction.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginWithMySQLi\changenameaction.php on line 12

here's my code:

```
session_start();

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET fname = ?, lname = ?, WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_SESSION['userSession']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();

$DBcon->close();
```

Do you know what i do wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: remove the comma before `where` - it means the statement failed preparation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hava a trailing comma your sql should be like this

```
UPDATE tbl_users SET fname = ?, lname = ? WHERE user_id = ?
```

Comment: Danku het werkt nu!

Comment: No problem, i'm glad to help

Answer (score 2):

The sql statement was failing the preparation stage so you should test that the statement is ok before proceeding with the other methods - the reason it failed was the extra comma before the `WHERE` clause

```
session_start();

require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET fname = ?, lname = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
if( $stmt && isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_SESSION['userSession']) ){
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_SESSION['userSession'] );
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
}
$DBcon->close();
```